# Schema Migrations Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

In my Rails 4 app I would like to collapse my migration files into one large file (similar to schema.rb) as it's time to do some housekeeping but I'm not sure on how to access the table in the database that stores migration data so that when I run a migration I don't receive any errors/conflicts.

**Question** How can I access and delete the data in the table that stores migration data?

Comment: Have you tried copy/pasting the `schema.rb` file into a migration file?

Comment: I don't have a problem creating the single migration file - but if I just change the migration files without considering the db I will get errors during a migration.

Comment: My current understanding is that you wish to have a file that stores all your migrations, so that you can clean em up? If so, I'd suggest looping through them and writing the data to a new file. Using methods like `File` `.glob` etc...

Comment: No - You are misunderstanding. Please see the question

Comment: ok somehow I didn't get your question

Comment: a more popular similar question here  - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3343534/753705

Answer (score 83):

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36451634) for Rails 4+ (TL;DR: use `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration`)

original answer from 2015 for Rails 3
(I'm a fossil, been on Rails since <1.0 )

for fun, you can also manipulate these in the console by making a model class for them...

```
class SchemaMigration < ActiveRecord::Base; self.primary_key = :version; end
```

then you can do SchemaMigration.all, SchemaMigration.last.delete, etc.

Really just a substitute for using SQL, and it is very rare that you would need to mess around at this low level… generally a bad idea but cool to see how to do it :)

Comment: This works - just run that code in Rails console to create a model in that console-instance.  Then you can select rows from that table with .where(:version => ...) and delete references to migrations as needed.  Very helpful since PGAdmin won't let you delete rows from tables that don't have a primary key specified with the gui.

Comment: 'generally'.  But there are edge cases.  Created a migration with a reference, adding `default: 1`  where 1 did not exist.  The migration halted... but the database was already altered.  Said migration could not run. This saved the day and sanity cycles for me.  Needless to say, this requires monkish patience and scrutiny before altering...

Comment: @JosephK  you can alter the schema_migrations table with psql commands. see  answer below.

Answer (score 64):

Another solution could be to access it through:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration
```

The answer given by David didn't work in my context.

Comment: This is so much cleaner than the defining a new model, it should really be the top answer.

Comment: I don't believe this is available in Rails 3.2, but it is the best solution for 4+.

Comment: This answer is much better anyway

Answer (score 21):

The `schema_migrations` table holds the revision numbers; with the last record being the most recently executed migration.  You can just manipulate these records manually.

Comment: Thanks - my question is how can I access this table - do I use the console? I want to delete all the records and then create a new migration - this sound ok?

Comment: If this does not need to be repeatable (i.e. none of this is in production yet), I would just use your db shell (psql or mysql, etc) and run a SQL query.

Comment: it's psql but never used the shell before

Comment: If you have a postgres role login as `sudo -u postgres psql`

Comment: Then run whatever update or delete statement you want to run.

Comment: Mark this as the answer, if you actually used this information to solve your issue.

Answer (score 11):

to get the last version:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.last.version
```

or all versions:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.all.map(&:version)
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why you want to do this but here you go:

ActiveRecord::Migrator.get_all_versions

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 7.1.3, this is no longer possible as `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration`
No longer inherits from

```
ActiveRecord::Model
```

As a workaround, you can just define a temporary model in your code:

```
class TemporarySchemaMigration < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'schema_migrations'
  self.primary_key = 'version'
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/436277da885

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 7.1+ use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_migration.table_name
```

See more at: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45908 and the final changelog
at https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v7.1.0

> Move ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata to an independent object.
>
> ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata no longer inherits from
> ActiveRecord::Base and is now an independent object that should be
> instantiated with a connection. This class is private and should not
> be used by applications directly. If you want to interact with the
> schema migrations table, please access it on the connection directly,
> for example: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_migration.
>
> Eileen M. Uchitelle

Answer (score -1):

I've had to do some cleanup of the sort: accumulation of seemingly trivial migrations create such pollution that things stop making sense.

As a last phase of development (not recommended once in production), you can clear out the schema_migrations table, consolidate your migrations (one-to-one with classes) and create a new table (beware: running `migrate` has different behaviours, depending on mysql vs postgresql)

@david-lowenfels  answer is perfect for this context.

All this, naturally, assumes you haven't made errors in keys, indices, defaults.  This is a serious task, but not an insensible one at the end of a development phase.